# Unable to install NVM on my Mac. Keeps getting curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server

Tags: node.js, macos, nvm

As the title states, I can't seem to install NVM on my mac. I run this command:

`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.11.1/install.sh | bash`

but I get this

`0curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server`

Been stuck on this for a week now. My macbook is up to date with the latest OS.

Answer (score 1):

open the url with the browser

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.11.1/install.sh

copy all the code into a .sh file in your computer,

run `chmod +x install.sh` (assuming the file is called install.sh)
then run `./install.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the commands listed in the [documentation](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install-script)

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
```

or

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
```

Comment: Those are the exact instructions I followed, no dice. I've tried installing it via brew as well, to no avail... Its strange as I can curl other things